# My `dictionary` recreating from scratch on update in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a method called `add_item(self, item)` in which I want to update the `items_category` value with more items

```
def add_item(self, item):

            self.items.update({item.category: {item.name: item}})
            """
            IN My Tests.
            self.nakkumart.add_item(Item("Call Of Duty", "Game", 3500, 1))
            self.nakkumart.add_item(Item("God Of War 3", "Game", 3500, 1))
            print(self.nakkumart.items['Game']['Call Of Duty'].price) >>>Raises KeyError 'Call Of Duty Not found'
            """
```

I think everytime am calling `add_item(Item)`, `item.category` is being recreated again and it's previous value lost. is it the way I have implemented my  `self.items.update({item.category: {item.name: item}})` or what should i do so that `print(len(self.nakkumart.items['Game']))` prints 2 on successive calls to `add_item(Item)`

Comment: If you try this statement print(self.nakkumart.items['Game']['God Of War 3'].price) , does it print the correct output?

Comment: yes it does print 3500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only updating the upper-level dictionary and not the inner one.

```
def add_item(self, item):
    self.items.update({item.category: {item.name: item}})
```

This says to replace the value of the 'Game' key with the new dictionary of `{item.name: item}` which tosses any other value.

You need to first grab the inner dictionary, update it, and then update the outer.

```
def add_item(self, item):
    cat_dict = self.items.get(item.category, {})
    cat_dict.update(item.name=item)
    self.items.update(item.category=cat_dict)
```

Comment: @EsirKings: modified to use another way to call `dict.update(key=value)` instead of creating a temporary dictionary.

Comment: what if I now want to delete a specific item `self.items[item.category].pop(item.name)` seems not to be working

Comment: unsure. Use a debugger to stop at that line or print the value of `self.items[item.category]` right before that line.